# How do i pass in package json lint folder name

Tags: node.js, eslint, lint

how to run lint command specific folder  its cover all files and folder in newproject folder

> npm run lint

currently in package JSON

```
"lint": "eslint . --ext .js",
"lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .js --fix",
```

i want like this   but its not work

```
"lint": "eslint . --ext newproject/.js",
"lint:fix": "eslint . --ext newproject/.js --fix",
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension is still `*.js`, but you want to run in `newproject` instead of `.` (current directory). So change your scripts to

```
"lint": "eslint newproject --ext .js",
"lint:fix": "eslint newproject --ext .js --fix",
```